# Snapcraft python only packages dependencies, not app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, snapcraft

I have a pretty standard python application, including `setup.py` and `requirements.txt`, which installs fine with `pip`:

```
$ pip install .
$ tree -L 1 env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/

env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
├── myAPP 
├── myAPP-0.1.0-py3.5.egg-info
...
```

I'd like to use snaps to build and deploy the application, and noticed that `snapcraft` only installs my app's dependencies, but not the app itself. It does build a wheel, but does not install it:

```
$ snapcraft
....
Building wheels for collected packages: myAPP, blist
...
Successfully built myAPP blist
/home/ubuntu/parts/myAPP/install/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --user 
    --no-compile --disable-pip-version-check --no-index 
    --find-links /home/ubuntu/parts/myAPP/packages blist 
    <other_requirements> --no-deps --upgrade
```

Does anyone know why `myAPP` is not part of the pip install?

For reference, the `snapcraft.yaml` is super simple at this stage, but I think should be all that's needed. Snapcraft is `v2.27.1` on Ubuntu 16.04

```
name: myAPP
version: '0.0.1'
summary: myAPP web application
description: |
  myAPP main web application

grade: devel 
confinement: strict

apps:
  myAPP:
    command: gunicorn myApp.wsgi
    daemon: simple
    plugs:
      - network-bind

parts:
  myAPP:
    plugin: python
    python-version: python3
    source: /opt/backend/
```

### Progress

I checked what packages are installed after building the application:

```
$ parts/myAPP/install/bin/pip list --format columns
Package                 Version  Location           
----------------------- -------- -------------------
appdirs                 1.4.2    
blist                   1.3.6    
myAPP                   0.1.0    /opt/backend
....
```

If I then manually re-run `pip install -U myAPP`, it does get included into `site-packages`. Will see if I can repeat the other build steps separately.

Comment: I'd love to help, but there's not enough information here for me to reproduce your issue. A minimal snapcraft.yaml that I can run would be great.

Comment: @Kyle thanks, I'll update Q. making progress too, the reason it doesn't install is that according to pip the *is* installed, but in `/opt/backend`, so the snapcraft python plugin filters it out: https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/snapcraft/plugins/python.py#L308

Comment: @Geotob The link doesn't work anymore. Does it still filter out some packages that are installed? Did you or others make progress and can tell me what must be true for a package (or the scripts contained therein) to be included in the final snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround by patching the snapcraft python plugin (on my system in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/plugins/python.py`):

```
--- /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/plugins/python.py  2017-02-17 13:45:14.000000000 +0000
+++ python.py   2017-03-02 01:53:54.993148168 +0000
@@ -298,7 +298,7 @@
                 # we want to avoid installing what is already provided in
                 # stage-packages
                 need_install = [k for k in wheel_names if k not in installed]
-                pip.install(need_install + ['--no-deps', '--upgrade'])
+                pip.install(wheel_names + ['--no-deps', '--upgrade', '--ignore-installed'])

     def _fix_permissions(self):
         for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.installdir):
```

I hope that there might be a cleaner solution to the problem? In the meantime, you can copy the patch above into a file called `patch.diff` and apply with:

```
sudo patch -b /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/plugins/python.py patch.diff
```